# heroku pg:reset DATABASE is not a heroku command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to reset a postgresql DB on my rails 5 app hosted on Heroku.
This is not my first time so I type with full assurance the following command :

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

And then it's the drama. The console gives me the following output :

```
 ▸    pg:reset is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant ps:resize?
 ▸    Run heroku _ to run heroku ps:resize DATABASE.
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

What I've tried with no success

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you prefer to use Heroku Web-site:

1. Go to https://postgres.heroku.com/databases
2. Select the database you want to reset
3. Scroll down and you will able to see Reset Database button.
4. Click "Reset Database"

or if you want to do with command line then you need to update heroku CLI

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: Hope It Helps!!

Comment: Thanks, I've re-installed the command line tool and now it's working. Don't know how or why my previous CLI installation got corrupted : /

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this command inside an app folder? if not then please use this syntax

```
heroku pg:reset [DATABASE] --app APP
```

Comment: I'm inside the correct folder while running the command. If I try yours, the output still gives me  
`▸    pg:reset is not a heroku command.`